# how to make button not react multiple click until the first-click events end

Tags: javascript, multimedia

I made a clock and coded to it to make the clock tell the time every quarter according to lecturers' requirement. But there is a problem, when I have multiple clicks, the clock tell the time again and again till the times of telling equal the times of clicks. I guess maybe I could make the button only work once. I did that in html:
<input= id="talkBTN" type="submit" value="Tell the time!" onclick=this.disabled>

but this way doesn’t solve the problem thoroughly as it just banned me from using the button.

this is the coding of "tell the time". I think I should use addEventListener and removeEventListener.

```
function tellTime(){
let currentTime = new Date();
timeWords.push("timeis");
numToWords(currentTime.getHours());
numToWords(currentTime.getMinutes());
console.log(timeWords);
timeTeller.addEventListener("ended", sayWords);
sayWords();
}



function sayWords(){
if (timeWords.length > 0) {
    timeTeller.src = soundURL + timeWords[0] + ".mp3";
    timeTeller.play();
    timeWords.shift();
    } else {
      timeTeller.removeEventListener("ended", sayWords);
      }
}

function numToWords(value){
if(value <= 20){
    timeWords.push(value);
    } else {
      let tens = Math.floor(value / 10);
      timeWords.push(tens * 10);
      if (value%10 != 0) {
          timeWords.push(value%10);
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had time to fully code this potential solution out, so I'm not sure how well it would solve your problem, but - what about using a global variable?

```
var foo = false;

function tellTime(){
if (!foo) {
    let currentTime = new Date();
    timeWords.push("timeis");
    numToWords(currentTime.getHours());
    numToWords(currentTime.getMinutes());
    console.log(timeWords);
    timeTeller.addEventListener("ended", sayWords);
    sayWords();
    } else { // do something else }
}



function sayWords(){
if (timeWords.length > 0) {
    timeTeller.src = soundURL + timeWords[0] + ".mp3";
    timeTeller.play();
    timeWords.shift();
    } else {
      timeTeller.removeEventListener("ended", sayWords);
      }
foo = true
}

function numToWords(value){
if(value <= 20){
    timeWords.push(value);
    } else {
      let tens = Math.floor(value / 10);
      timeWords.push(tens * 10);
      if (value%10 != 0) {
          timeWords.push(value%10);
          }
    }
}
```

and then in the function that "finishes" one round (I think sayWords) you set it to true.

So the process would be, you click the button, the starter function checks the global, if it is on, then it skips, if it's off then it continues and turns the global on. The process continues until the last function in the flow, and that one changes the global off.

So then things would only happen when the process finishes.

Another potential solution is that you could turn the disable of the button on and off with javascript. Basically the same process, but instead of checking if the global variable is on or off, you just find and disable the button at the beginning, and then find and enable the button when the process is done.

```
function tellTime(){
let btn = $('#btn').attr(“disabled”, true);
let currentTime = new Date();
timeWords.push("timeis");
numToWords(currentTime.getHours());
numToWords(currentTime.getMinutes());
console.log(timeWords);
timeTeller.addEventListener("ended", sayWords);
sayWords();
}



function sayWords(){
if (timeWords.length > 0) {
    timeTeller.src = soundURL + timeWords[0] + ".mp3";
    timeTeller.play();
    timeWords.shift();
    } else {
      timeTeller.removeEventListener("ended", sayWords);
      }
let btn = $('#btn').attr(“disabled”, false);
}

function numToWords(value){
if(value <= 20){
    timeWords.push(value);
    } else {
      let tens = Math.floor(value / 10);
      timeWords.push(tens * 10);
      if (value%10 != 0) {
          timeWords.push(value%10);
          }
    }
}
```

does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

May you look for something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce or https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.throttle